# OpenVPN Tunnel in Tunnel

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn

I want to connect to my OpenVPN server which inside the campus network from the internet.

Getting into the campus network is possible through SSH or (another) OpenVPN connection. After that I can connect to my Server.

Is it possible to have one OpenVPN file establishing both connections? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread [Double VPN || 2 Hop VPN || VPN-over-VPN](http://forums.openvpn.net/topic7483.html) deals with this problem.

Below is the last and best solution which might apply (or not) to your case :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead.

Comment: @pandalion98: Well, this happens after 6 years. You did notice that the answer is from 2012 before downvoting it?

Comment: https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=7483